# Extend a single week's win/loss ratio calculation to a whole season

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions

I'm quite inexperienced at SQL, and I'm trying to improve a query in a small project.

The database schema looks somewhat like this. (I've reduced to relevant information, if there seems to be something missing please point it out):

[image: basic schema]

It's a database of a fantasy sports league, and we want to calculate an 'all-play record'.

My understanding is that the 'all-play record' is generated by taking every team in a given league's scores for a given week and assuming they all play each other.

I've written a query that does this for a given week:

```
WITH weekly_points_table (team_id, max_points)
AS
(
  SELECT teams.id, SUM(player_scores.points) as max_points
  FROM player_scores
  INNER JOIN weeks ON weeks.id = player_scores.week_id
  INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = player_scores.team_id
  WHERE (team_id IN (?) AND weeks.number = ? and weeks.year = ?)
  GROUP BY teams.id
)
SELECT *
FROM weekly_points_table
WHERE max_points < (SELECT max_points
  FROM weekly_points_table
  WHERE team_id = ?
)
```

The list of team_ids, the given week number/year, and the final team_id are passed in.

Wins are calculated with the above query, losses are calculated by simply flipping the sign, and ties are just (count of all teams - 1) - (wins + losses) for a given week.

But now I'm at a loss at how to extend this to a given season.

A season is a collection of weeks where the year is identical, and week numbers go from 1 to 16.

Right now we're literally just taking the single-week query and running it in a for-loop. (Before that, we were using nested for loops to calculate the wins/losses/ties, and you can imagine how slow that can be.)

Pretty much, how do I take the calculated wins/losses for a given week and add them up for all 16 weeks?

Comment: I've found a solution to my problem, and made a gist that was slightly too long to post as a comment:
https://gist.github.com/shadefinale/fa1543ddcd0e423986f8

It uses the information from the CTE and counts rows where the weekly points are higher than the target team's weekly points.

Comment: Yes, some things are missing: Postgres version, data types and PK / UNIQUE constraints - you can get everything with `\d tbl` in psql. Exact form of parameter values. Some sample values and a corresponding desired result to clarify would be great, too. And it's ok (and actually welcome) to answer your own question if you have found a useful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a standard [many-to-many implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860) ...

```
SELECT week_id
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE week_points > team_points) AS losses
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE week_points < team_points) AS wins
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE week_points = team_points) AS draws
--     , count(*) AS total -- redundant check
FROM (
   SELECT week_id, team_id, sum(points) AS week_points
        , first_value(sum(points)) OVER (PARTITION BY week_id
                                         ORDER BY team_id <> 7) AS team_points
   FROM  (SELECT id AS week_id FROM weeks WHERE year = ?) w  -- your year
   CROSS  JOIN unnest(?::int[]) t(team_id)  -- your teams, see below!
   JOIN   player_scores p USING (week_id, team_id)
   WHERE  EXISTS (  -- only weeks where the team actually played
      SELECT 1 FROM player_scores
      WHERE week_id = p.week_id
      AND   team_id = ?  -- your team_id
      )
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) sub
WHERE  team_id <> ?  -- your team_id again
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Returns something like:

```
week_id | losses | wins | draws
--------+--------+------+------
1       | 3      | 0    | 0
2       | 5      | 7    | 0
3       | 2      | 2    | 1
```

The key feature is the window function `first_value()` to get the weekly score for the team in the same query. Aggregate functions can be nested in window functions. Consider the sequence of events:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied in PHP/PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860)

The aggregate `FILTER` clause requires Postgres **9.4+**. There are other ways. Details in this closely related answer on SO:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27141193/939860)

Assuming you provide your list of teams as array literal in the form `'{1,2,3}'`. There are other ways ...

Comment: Window functions are so cool!

This solution given calculates the all-play record across a given season, which we actually had a way of doing on a week-to-week basis but this absolutely blows what I had out of the water.

Doing something like this
`SELECT SUM(count(week_points < team_points OR NULL)) OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS wins,
             SUM(count(week_points > team_points OR NULL)) OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS losses,
             SUM(count(week_points = team_points OR NULL)) OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS draws`

Allows me to calculate the sum of wins/losses/draws across the given season as well! Thanks!